# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I do not get an error when I delete the component menu I created specially from where I put it, but I get an error when my component is there. Thank you for your comments already.

````
import Menu from './Navigator'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export default class HeaderLeft extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={check:false}
    }
    render() {
        return (<SafeAreaView><View onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() => { this.setState({ check: !this.state.check }) }} style={styles.align}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} size={16} color={"#2D6A4F"} /><Menu check={this.state.check}></Menu></View></SafeAreaView>)
    }

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    align: {
        height: 60, display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 20
    },

});```
````

Comment: From which line does the error come from?

Comment: Are you saying `this.setState` isn't working, or `this.check` isn't working? Your question is unclear.

Comment: This error is located at:
    in Menu (at HeaderLeft.js:22)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at HeaderLeft.js:21)

Comment: @Maskot check HeaderLeft.js file and add its code to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try by making the changes as the below code in your code.:

add below in the constructor:

```
this.handleResponderCapture = this.handleResponderCapture.bind(this)
```

Add below method:

```
handleResponderCapture = () => {
    this.setState({
        check: !this.state.check
    })
}
```

Make changes as below in View

```
<View
    onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={this.handleResponderCapture}
    style={styles.align}
>
```